# Pure (dynamic) HTML5-website with Backend

Tags: php, html, api, dynamic

Couldn't find anything about this online so I'm giving it a try here. (Not sure what to look for in google so maybe that's why I couldn't find it).

My client wants (for some strange reason) a dynamic, pure HTML5-website with no PHP at all. The webpages can be created with PHP, but after he is done, he wants it to (automatically) generate HTML5-webpages so these can be put online on a server with no PHP.

Is this at all even possible? Writing an API myself that gets the content from the server and converts it to HTML5 is not really an option due to time ...

Thanks

Comment: Define "dynamic", please. Stuff like http://jekyllrb.com/ let you render a set of templates and blog/article-like content down to static HTML, but if you're talking about something like a forum it's going to need a backend.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. No, you don't need to write an API yourself, you can use existing stuff, like jQuery AJAX calls. No, you don't need to '_convert content from the server to HTML5_' - no idea how you came up with that idea.

Comment: @MarcinWolny What will the AJAX calls communicate with if there is no back end?

Comment: @vascowhite AJAX calls don't require any PHP backend layer. In fact - they don't even require any valid HTML code, you can pull plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FYI:** If what you want is a [Single Page Application](http://singlepageappbook.com/goal.html), you're asking the wrong question.

Seems like what your client wants is a pure HTML site because he might have the idea that pure HTML sites are better for SEO.

**What do to?**

**Alternative 1:**

Create a different server to generate pages. Either local (with [vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/)) or in another remote server. Have your content generated there by using a CMS of your choice.

Periodically generate a mirror of your site using a tool like [HTTrack](https://www.httrack.com/) or [wget](https://superuser.com/a/14436/167672). Hand this mirror to your client.

**Alternative 2:**

Use a static site generator like [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/). Have the server run a cron task to automatically generate HTML from the changes.

**Alternative 3:**

Be the expert and explain to him that his ideas are probably unfounded.

Comment: Alternative 3 being the best. :-)

Comment: Aha, thanks for your answer (and also to the others who commented). It seems like alternative 3 is the best, obviously, but since I'm not the boss I can't really decide on that. I am gonna look at the other alternatives you provided, alt 1 sounds the best so far. Thanks for the quick answers!

Comment: For those who are interested, I choose Jekyll. I'm trying it out now. Easy to install with terminal

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use the HTML5 Filesystem API and Javascript to read/write from a JSON file as a backend. It's definitely not ideal, but it would satisfy your requirements.